# Should I worry about buying this bike?

Tags: motorcycle, maintenance, buying

I'm looking at buying a 2014 Ninja 1000 with 1,400 miles on it. I asked the guy about the maintenance he's performed and he said he hasn't done anything to it so far. I know you should change the oil after a few hundred miles, but he hasn't done it yet and said that he always waits to change the oil after 3,000 miles on the bikes he buys.

Should I be worried about buying this bike based on that? Is that enough of a maintenance mistake that I should pass on the bike?

Comment: Nope, 1400 miles is basically new, check for other info as to why is he selling so quickly , any issues with documentation etc. Also do a through inspection before your buy, based on oil changed i dont think will be an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I agree with the basic tenants of what @Anarach has said in the comment, there is one possible blaring issue with the motorcycle, that being: ***was it broke in properly***. I'm not talking about, what do people on the forums say, I'm talking about *how Kawasaki says it should be broken in*. In the owners manual (which you can [download here](http://www.kawasaki.com/ServiceManuals/Manual/ZX1000MEF)), it states:

> The first 1600 KM (1000 mile) that the motorcycle is ridden is designated as the break-in period. If the motorcycle is not used carefully during this period, you may very well end up with a "broken down" instead of a "broken in" motorcycle after a few thousand kilometers.
>
> The following rules should be observed during the break-in period.
>
> - The following is the maximum recommended engine speed during the break-in period:

```
Distance traveled             Max engine speed
0~800 km (0~500 mile)         4000 rpm
800~1600 km (500~1000 mile)   6000 rpm
```

Every person who is trying to sell a motorcycle will tell you, "*Oh, I followed those rules exactly.*" ... but how do you know for sure? There is no way to measure anything. There is no way to verify. More than likely, they have followed the rules, but you just don't know for sure. This would leave a *huge* gap in my mind telling me to walk away from it.

The break-in is a very important procedure. Without following it to the letter, any warranty which exists with Kawasaki will be null and void.

Comment: Good point, we can never be sure if he broke in the bike properly, @paulster is there any way to find it ? apart from judging him based on his looks ROFL..

Comment: @Anarach - That's the real issue, *you have to trust what the person is telling you*, though you also need to ask the right questions and get a feel for everything. This is *very* important for new bikes if you want to maintain the warranty from the manufacturer. If you aren't worried about that, then it's no issue.

Comment: If I'm correctly reading the chart in the owner's manual, it also says the oil should be changed for the first time at 600 miles.  Since that did not happen, in principle that could already have voided the warranty, if Kawasaki wants to be strict about it

Comment: @NateEldredge - I agree, but it would be a lot harder to prove, I think that it had not been changed, though they might require some kind of proof of change I guess (receipt).

Comment: Newer cars have a "maintenance minder" which illuminates a light when oil changes or other service is due. The mechanic is supposed to manually reset the light when the service is performed. In principle, the vehicle's computer could record the mileage at which this was done (or not), and the dealer could retrieve that data in case of a major warranty claim. No idea if this particular vehicle has anything of the sort, though.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Just wondering, if _there is no way to verify_ the breaking in correctness, how would you loose the warranty if you did not do it properly? (Mainly asking about the RPM restriction, because the oil change is easy to enforce with servicing proof of some kind.)

Comment: @AlinPurcaru - I believe I was talking about a user/owner/rider here, not a dealership. If one were to not break in the bike correctly and something happened, I'd suspect a dealership could put more effort to bear on figuring this out. There is probably certain wear patterns which form when proper break-in occurs, or visa-versa. This would point them towards a blown warranty where as you as an individual wouldn't be able to pull the engine apart when trying to purchase the bike to see a difference. Hopefully that explains what I mean.